# retrieve facebook details albums

Tags: php, facebook

I'm tried retrieve the album details with this code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '',
  'secret' => '',
  'cookie' => true,
));

Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false; 
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
if ($user) {
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$album = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums/?access_token={$access_token}");
    print_r($album); 
}else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array('canvas' => 1,
                 'fbconnect' => 0,
                 'req_perms' => 
                  'user_photos,friends_photos'
            ));
}
```

the code above returns an empty array,why? Can someone point my error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to understand what you are doing here not just follow a tutorial (or a combination of tutorials!):

1. Don't use: `Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;`
2. The first `if($user)` statement is not needed if you don't really need the user data `$user_profile`
3. If there's a current user no need for getting the access token since the SDK will take care of that
4. why using `file_get_contents` if you are using the SDK?!
5. The new SDK implementation (following the OAuth 2.0) requires you to use `scope` instead of `req_perms`
6. after creating the login URL you need to actually use it!

Here is a better code to get you started:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '',
  'secret' => '',
  'cookie' => true,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_photos,friends_photos'));
    echo "<script>top.location.href = '" . $loginUrl . "';</script>";
}
```

I **strongly** recommend that you read the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) before just trying some random code.

Comment: Well, I downloaded the PHP-SDK and he came along with this example, I tried do works fine, to go after write the optimizations.

I'm using 
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;

why by default the API url use SSL: https://graph.facebook.com
I do not see  this in $CURL_OPTS

Comment: I'm now using 'scope' instead of 'req_perms' all works fine. Thanks very much :)